# Mysql Use Column Value In One Table If Join Doesn't Exist To Second Table

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to find a way to return the most favorite color found in the following example.  If possible, in the same query.

```
TableA

id | name | secondFavoriteColor
-----------------------
0  | john | blue
1  | sam  | red

TableB

id | userid | favoriteColor
----------------------------
0  | 1      | orange


SELECT TableA.name, [[mostFavoriteColor]] FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON TableA.id = TableB.userid
```

This should return

```
name | mostFavoriteColor
-------------------------
john | blue
sam  | orange
```

Basically, TableA would contain a default value in the column "secondFavoriteColor", and TableB would contain the actual favorite if it exists per user.  TableB doesn't always have a record for each user, however if the JOIN doesn't work, then it should return the value of "secondFavoriteColor" from TableA under the common alias "mostFavoriteColor", and the output table would be two columns with "name" from TableA and "mostFavoriteColor" which is pulled from TableB IF successfully joined, or TableA IF the join fails.

Any ideas as to how this could work with the same query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need left join on table b so if there is no row found for a user in table b it will return null and then use `COALESCE` to pick first not null value

```
SELECT a.name, COALESCE(b.favoriteColor, a.secondFavoriteColor) mostFavoriteColor
FROM TableA a
LEFT JOIN TableB b ON a.id = b.userid
```